# Should I use separate collection or embed fields that I know won't be used for all models. MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongoose, schema

### Background:

I'm planning an app that will have 3 types of posts, for *n* number of games; Single-posts, team-posts, coach-posts. Now I'm not sure of the best Schema for a single *type* of post.

The posts of a certain type share a couple fundamental attributes, like: user_id, comments, status, etc. But the fields relevant to the game will be unique.

These are the two possibilities I'm considering:

#### 1. Separate collection for each game:

As you can see the *playerposts* type requires different fields for each game but has a similar structure.

```
// game1_playerposts
{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    user_id: ObjectId(),
    game: ObjectId(),
    comments: [{
        user_id: ObjectId(),
        comment: String,
        score: Number
    }],
    rank: {
        name: String,
        abbr: String,
        img: String
    },
    roles: [String],
    gamemode: [String]
}

// game2_playerposts
{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    user_id: ObjectId(),
    game: ObjectId(),
    comments: [{
        user_id: ObjectId(),
        comment: String,
        score: Number
    }],
    level: {
        name: String,
        abbr: String,
        img: String
    },
    champions: [String],
    factions: [{
        name: String,
        abbr: String,
        img: String
    }]
}
```

#### 2. One collection for all games:

This way I only need one collection, and will always only use the fields I need, and the rest would remain empty.

```
{
    _id : ObjectId(),
    user_id : ObjectId(),
    game1 : {
        game: ObjectId(),
        rank: {
            name: String,
            abbr: String,
            img: String
        },
        roles: [String],
        gamemodes: [String]
    },
    game2 : {
        game: ObjectId(),
        level: {
            name: String,
            abbr: String,
            img: String
        },
        champions: [String],
        factions: {
            name: String,
            abbr: String,
            img: String
        }
    },
    game_n {
    ...
    },
    comments : [{
        user_id: ObjectId(),
        comment: String,
        score: Number
    }],
}
```

#### What's better?

Which one of these options would be better suited? Performance is important, but I also want it to be simple to add to the Schema when we decide to add support for another game in the future.

Comment: MongoDB is schemaless. I don't see why you have to have fields you know won't be used. Why not just have a separate document for each individual player post and that document will have the schema that relates to the type of post it is? I mean you can have in a single collection both of the documents that you have as examples under the **"Separate collection for each game"** header.

Comment: @NoOutlet Thanks, I've been following some tutorials on the MEAN stack, so I guess I got confused when most of them require you to create a model using the mongoose.Schema.

Comment: Okay and to be fair, I haven't worked with Mongoose and defining schemas for it, so I don't know how exactly it will work on that end. But if it gets rid of the schemaless nature of MongoDB, that would be a considerable disadvantage of using it...

Comment: Well it seems you've answered my question then. There would be no reason to use Option 1. And as far as the Schemas go, I believe I could set a couple different ones for each game that write to the same collections. Might actually be helpful when done on certain endpoints of my API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB is schemaless.

I don't see why you have to have fields you know won't be used. Why not just have a separate document for each individual player post and that document will have the schema that relates to the type of post it is?

You can have in a single collection both of the documents that you have as examples under the "**Separate collection for each game**" header.

I have not worked with Mongoose, but if using it removes the benefits of MongoDB being schemaless, I don't think it would be as popular a tool as it is, so I think there's a way for it to work.